# How to Callback 1 function after 0.5s by SetTimer on C++

Tags: c++, mfc, callback

I try to make a ButtonA, I want to get data when pess ButonA is pressed, however it just gets data one time, how can I get data in real-time (or after each 0.5s)

I try to find, and I found Settimer, and Callback function, however, i don't know how to use these  2 functions,
My ideal is after 0.5s by Settimer, the function to get-data will be called again... Or some one have new Ideal?

Comment: You should elaborate your question. It's hard to understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a callback you need a message handler. You have already added a message handler for the button click. Now also add a message handler for the WM_TIMER message. It will be named OnTimer by the add message wizard. In the button click handler call

```
SetTimer(1, 500, NULL);
```

This will cause the WM_TIMER message to come in every 500 milliseconds, which will call your OnTimer function. The button click handler and the OnTimer handler can both call your function that gets the data.

When you want it to stop call KillTimer.